# Getting segmentation fault when sorting an linked list

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, linked-list

So here is the my sorting function, i'm not swapping the info from the linked list just the pointers for the next node. I have a similar function that sorts by the price of the car that works perfectly, when i use to sort by the year of the car i get segmentation fault 11.

```
void ordenaCrescenteAno(ELEMCAR *iniLista){
  ELEMCAR *aux1 = NULL;
  ELEMCAR *aux2 = NULL;
  ELEMCAR *maior = NULL;
  ELEMCAR *troca = NULL;

  if(iniLista == NULL){
    printf("Lista Vazia\n");
    return;
  }

  for(aux1 = iniLista; aux1 != NULL; aux1 = aux1 -> seguinte){
    maior = aux1;
    for(aux2 = aux1; aux2 != NULL; aux2 = aux2 -> seguinte){
       if(aux2->info.ano > maior->info.ano){
          maior = aux2;
       }
    }
    if(maior != aux1){
      troca->seguinte = aux1->seguinte;
      aux1->seguinte = maior->seguinte;
      maior->seguinte = troca->seguinte;
    }

 }
}
```

I'm gonna put here the details of the linked list:

```
typedef struct carro{
    char matricula[7];
    char marca[30];
    char modelo[30];
    int ano;
    char classe[30];
    float preco;
    char combustivel[10];
    int dataInspecao;
    int dataRevisao;
    char observacoes[100];
    int estado;
}CARINFO;

typedef struct CarElem{
    CARINFO info;
    struct CarElem *seguinte;
}ELEMCAR;
```

What am i doing wrong? I can't figure it out, since i have a similar function that works, but i'm sorting by the "preco" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`troca` is initialized to null so `troca->sequinte` will fault

Use this instead

```
struct CarElem *troca; replace troca definition

troca = aux1->sequinte; replace troca->sequinte line with this
maior->sequinte = troca; remove ->sequinte from troca
```

I realized that the above code snippet was buggy.

In your swapping part

```
if (maior != aux1)
{
  CARINFO carswap = aux1->info; // Copy the info into a temporary variable
  aux1->info = maior->info;     // Move info from maior to aux1
  maior->info = carswap;        // Move info from temporary variable to maior
}
```

Hope this code snippet does what you require

Comment: By doing this, when i try print the cars of my linked list after sorting i only get one car, and i have 3 in my linked list, help?